# Calling method from another class which relates to Arraylist

Tags: java

I am building an application with a `Room` class which is abstract and a `Standard` class which inherits from `Room`. I have then created a `Hostel` class. Within the `Hostel` class is `ArrayList<Room> rooms` to which rooms can be added. I have created a method in the `Hostel` class which shows all available rooms but when I try and instantiate this in another class (`MainGUI`) nothing is shown. As far as I can see this is because I am creating a new hostel each time I click the button but would like to know how to pass the data across instead of creating a new hostel each time. Below are the relevant snippets of code.

`Hostel Class`

```
public Hostel()
{
    rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
}

public void showAvail()
{
    for (Room room : rooms)
    {
        if (room.available == true) 
        {
                 theString = room.getRoomData() + "\n";
                 //System.out.println("Available Rooms" + "\n" + theString);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,theString);
        }
    }
}

public void addRoom(Room theRoom)
{
    rooms.add(theRoom);
}
```

`MainGUI Class`

```
roomsFreeB.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Hostel host = new Hostel();
        host.showAvail();
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where are you filling `rooms`?

Comment: @Kevin i have a constructor for Standard Rooms within the standard class then are then added to the Array list in the Hostel class

Comment: Are they added to the `Hostel` in its constructor?  If so, post that code too.  If not, that's your problem, the code to add the `Room`s is never called.

Comment: i have added the add room constructor.

Comment: `addRoom()` is a method, not a constructor.  It doesn't get called automatically, and you never call it in the code you've posted, so the `Hostel` and its `rooms` never get `Room`s added to it.

Comment: @Kevin are you familiar with the IDE BlueJ?

Comment: I've heard of it, I use `vim`.  But your IDE shouldn't matter for this question as it is.  Why?

Comment: within BlueJ you can create objects of classes within the IDE so i have been creating a `Hostel` object `Standard` objects then calling the `addRoom()` method within the Hostel object to populate the arraylist

Comment: And have you tried calling `showAvail()` on the object you added the rooms to?

Comment: Yes and it works absolutely fine, this is why i am so confused.

Comment: When you run this as it is, it doesn't add any rooms to the hostel.  It doesn't take the same instance you added the rooms to manually, it creates a new one.  You can either stop it between creating that instance (`host`, in the `ActionListener`), add rooms, and then let it continue, or (and this is preferable, especially for debugging here), add some rooms in code between creating it and listing the rooms.

Comment: is there any way to call the method from the `Hostel` class without creating a new `Hostel` instance each time?

Comment: You could make everything in the `Hostel` class static, but I don't think that's a great idea.  You should probably use an instance variable within `MainGUI` and call the methods on that one.

Comment: Get the feeling im gonna have to look at this from the beginning and change my design, Thanks for your help and patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what you thought, you are making a new ArrayList each time you click the button so you will never see the  data. You should begin by creating a `hostel` object in your `MainGUI` class,

`private Hostel hostel;`

this will allow previously entered information to be referenced

Answer (score 1):

Unless you omitted code between the `Hostel host = new Hostel();` and `host.showAvail();`, you never add any rooms to the hostel so there are no available rooms (or any at all) to show.  You need to either add rooms to `host` after you create it and before you `showAvail`, or create a `Hostel` instance variable, fill it somewhere, and then call `showAvail` on that.

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to see how you initialize your **rooms** inside **Hostel**. And if you like to initialize Hostel once only, do it outside of Listener. In this case it must not be a field inside MainGUI.

Comment: i have edited the code showing where the array list is initialized within the hostel class

Comment: I just wondered if you were sure, that rooms are created and added to that ArrayList?

Comment: within my hostel class i can call the method showAvail() and available rooms are shown, it is when i try and do this in the MainGUI class where my troubles are

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Hostel host = new Hostel();
    host.showAvail();
}
```

In the previous code, the object is created and then destroyed once the method is done. The variable **host** is a local variable and consequently lives only during the execution of the method.

Depending on what you want to do, you should declare your host variable inside the main method  or declare an array of hostel inside the main method again.

Comment: in the action performed i would just like the method to work and thus show me my available rooms via JOptionPane as in the showAvail method

Comment: @John Doe: By working, do you mean JOptionPane is not showing ?

Comment: i create a hostel from the hostel class, this hostel then has rooms added to it, working would mean that the rooms which have been added show on the click of the button roomsFreeB

Comment: @John Doe: The constructor initialize the arraylist of rooms but do not create any rooms so your program is not showing anything since no room are available to be displayed

Comment: Since you don't call the `host.addRoom()` method between creating the `Hostel` and showing its rooms, it never has any rooms added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating new Hostel each time. I guess there will be to `Room`s in the ArrayList.

You need to create the Hostel Object outside the actionPerformed. And in your case it should be created only one time. And on this created Hostel object you will be adding the `Room` object.

If the question is where to do it.. Its left to you. Its upon your design.

For eg it can be.

You can create a class called `ABC` inside which you can create the hostel object. Write a static method called getHostel(). Then call ABC.getHostel()

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right that everytime action is performed a new Hostel is created and so is the list of rooms associated with hostel.

On click of button you would know which hostel you want to show (May be reading your application database or something), in case this is the first time your hostel will have empty room, else once you have read the hostel information you would also know about rooms which belong to the hostel, which can then be passed to your hostel object either through constructor or setter method.

Code snippet:

```
createHostel(String hostelName) {
   //read from database
   //No hostel with hostelname found create a new hostel else if hostel is found send   the same (by this time hostel object would have room information also
}
```

Your action

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
   //MyFactory.getHostel(String hostelName)
   //Once you have hostel object call showAvail on it, if its new you will get nothing else you will get all the rooms available
}
```

Hope this gives you some insight.